# Is it possible to get mstest with /publish option without needing to install Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, junit, tfs, mstest

I am trying to publish some junit.xml test results into my TFS build - I have transformed them into .trx files and they display fine, so long as I use MSTest.exe with /publish - but I have many users who do not have this version of MSTest installed on their build agents.

According to [Command-Line options for publishing test results](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243151.aspx), the prerequisites for the version of MSTest with the /publish option are:

> Visual Studio Ultimate, Visual Studio Premium, or Visual Studio Test Professional

Also, the Test Agents (e.g. [Visual Studio 2013 Test Agent](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40750)) only seem to install the version of mstest without the publish functionality.

Is there a way (for example, can I redistribute?) to get MSTest.exe with the publishing functionality onto TFS build agents without needing to purchase (and install) one of those copies of Visual Studio?

Comment: As long as you have a licenced copy for development, you can install onto the build server without the need to purchase an additional licence

Comment: Thank you, yes. But in the case of all devs only being on Pro versions, then they need to purchase at least one copy of the more expensive version?

Comment: yes if you don't have a licenced version between you. it sounds like you have a higher version, do you queue any builds?